# Xcode Logfile After Testing on iPhone Strange Output

Tags: iphone, logging

When I am Testing my app on my iPhone, when the app starts, i am getting this Strange Output:

DataFile: file Open error: /var/mobile/Library/Keyboard/de_DE-dynamic-Text.dat, (permission denied)

What does it mean?
And what To do against it?

EDIT:
It seems that the file open error occurs in that part of my code, because when I "comment" it away the error wont show:

```
NSMutableDictionary *InfoDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"AppInformation" ofType:@"plist"]]];

    NSString *Checkstring = [InfoDic objectForKey:@"Language"];

    if ([Checkstring isEqualToString:@"empty"]) {
 UIAlertView *determineLang = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select a Language" message:@"Choose a Language"
delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Deutsch" otherButtonTitles:@"English", nil];
 determineLang.tag=5;
 [determineLang show];

 }
```

Edit2: seems that every of my alertviews in every of my apps are causing the same issue, 
must be a problem with the jailbreak of the iPhone...

Comment: This user was getting the same error and updated his post with how he fixed it.  Not sure if it applies to your problem as you didn't provide any information on your project.  Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184428/iphone-plist-add-new-string-to-array

Comment: I don't understand what he changed to make it disappear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with jailbroken iDevices and UIAlertViews!
Due to the fact that it seems to not have any further impact on the behavior of the App itself I would say everyone facing the Problem has to live with it.